# Breeze.js - How do I create/add child objects to a parent that I am also creating?

Tags: breeze

Given the following EF model:

```
public class Order
{
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public string CustomerName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
  ...
}

// OrderDetail has a composite key of OrderId and ProductId
public class OrderDetail
{
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

In my MVC4 web app (using HotTowel SPA template - Durandal, Breeze.js, Knockout, etc.), I have created a view for creating a new Order and addding/removing OrderDetail items.

In datacontext.js, I have the following:

```
var createOrder = function() {
  return manager.createEntity('Order');
};
```

In my viewmodel orderadd.js, I am calling createOrder:

```
order = ko.observable();

activate = function() {
  initLookups();
  order(datacontext.createOrder());
}
```

Question: How do I create/add new OrderDetail items to the Order object and save the entire new Order object in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Do it the same way that you are creating an order, just simply add the navigation property back to the order from the order detail.

```
var createOrderDetail = function() {
    return manager.createEntity('OrderDetail');
};

var order = ko.observable();

activate = function() {
    initLookups();
    order(datacontext.createOrder());
    var orderDetail = datacontext.createOrderDetail();
    orderDetail.order(order());
}
```

Another option is to set the order when you are creating the entity orderDetail but I have found there is a slight timing issue that Knockout gets mad about while the entity is create and not all of the values have been assigned that are required in the view.  An example of this way is -

```
var createOrderDetail = function(order) {
    return manager.createEntity('OrderDetail', { order: order });
};

var order = ko.observable();

activate = function() {
    initLookups();
    order(datacontext.createOrder());
    var orderDetail = datacontext.createOrderDetail(order());
}
```